# Error in creating a stored procedure using mysql workbench

Tags: mysql

I am new to stored procedures, and I am having a hard time creating a stored procedure. I just want to select a field in the table but as I create the procedure it has this kind of error.

[image: screenshot]

I hope you can help. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Don't use " use backtick(`) or don't quote at all, check your porcedure does not already exist, set delimiters as described here - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html. And please don't use images in your question use text.